# Tomcat application cannot be started

Tags: git, maven, tomcat

As of [this figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9v32.png), in my Tomcat server, I have a web application (vitheakids-admin) and another application (vitheaWs) that provides web services to a third application (an Android one) and has a jar with a set of vitheakids-admin's classes as a Maven dependency. Also, my code for vitheakids-admin is in a different Git branch than my code for vitheaWs (*master* and *webservices* respectively), but *webservices* has an older version of vitheakids-admin as well.

Everything was working fine until today, when I installed an up-to-date jar of vitheakids-admin's classes to Maven local repo and my webservices app, despite deploying successfully, does not start anymore (if I do it manually, it gives a *FAIL - Application at context path /vitheaWs could not be started* error). At first I thought it could be any change to vitheaWs, but I had reset to the last working commit and I figured it could only be a problem with the jar. However, there are no errors regarding vitheakids-admin (the web application is working as it should), so the jar should be ok as well... but somehow it is not.

I created and installed different versions of the jar (always with the same name) based the latest commits to *master*, but the only one that allows vitheaWs to be started on Tomcat is the version using the classes as they are in the *webservices* local branch. This does not do for me since that version does not have the code that I currently need so that users of the Android app can log in and use the web services - and that code that I need was working yesterday.

I did not alter pom.xml, I double checked every step I made and have tried to create jars for my latest working commits, but nothing works anymore. I also googled endlessly but found no one facing similar issues.

Is it possible that the code of vitheakids-admin in *webservices* is getting in the way of the installed jar? It is my only bet now, and still it does not make much sense given that I had one of the latest commits on master working fine with the webservices yesterday. Any idea of what could cause this? Has anyone been through a similar issue?

Thanks in advance.

PS: I am not posting code for now because I have not been changing it, but if anyone would prefer to look at it (or git logs, etc.), I can post anything later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!

Basically, the latest versions of the jar included a class that wasn't mapped in applicationContext.xml. Added that mapping and everything is ok now.